# Enable Android Preference Item programmatically in Java

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I have got the following Problem: I have to set a Preference Enabled if some environment is given. So I have written the following Code in the `PreferenceActivity` in the `onPostCreate` function:

```
if (myVariable == null){
     findPreference("myPref").setEnabled(true);
}
```

Normally this Preference is set disabled in the XML.

Now, since `findPreference` is deprecated, I want to know how to solve this a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is deprecated, because it is irrelevant to a fragment-based activity:

> This method was deprecated in API level 11.
>
> This function is not relevant for a modern fragment-based PreferenceActivity.

However, if you decide to build your `PreferenceActivity` without fragments, it is perfectly fine for you to use this method (You *have* to use it, to be honest). If you do want to use fragments, read more about them in `PreferenceActivity`s [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment).